# GIT Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github

I've cloned a private repo, forked it and made som changes into a feature branch. When I try to push these changes into the repo i get the following message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried to delete the git credentials from my windows computer controlpanel>credentials but it's still showing me the same error.

Is there any chance that I have to log in and out from my terminal to git? If that would be the case, how do I do that?

I've also tried to push with git push --set-upstream origin  but it's just showing me the same error.

Have anyone of you seen this before?

Thanks beforehand,
Erik

Comment: Check if your public key exists.

Comment: How do I do that? Tried to paste  " ls -al ~/.ssh " into Git bash and got the following: " drwxr-xr-x 1 40114592 1049089   0 Oct 17 11:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 40114592 1049089   0 Oct 17 11:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 40114592 1049089 799 Oct 17 11:03 known_hosts "

Comment: You should check if your local device has the `id_rsa.pub`, then check if the device host the repo have the publickey content in file known_hosts.

Comment: you can always ssh into your gitserver `ssh git@gitserver` and see if your key is associated with any user

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**"Help, I keep getting a 'Permission Denied (publickey)' error when I push!"**

This means, on your local machine, you haven't made any SSH keys. Not to worry. Here's how to fix:

1. Open git bash (Use the Windows search. To find it, type "git bash")
   or the Mac Terminal. Pro Tip: You can use any *nix based command
   prompt (but not the default Windows Command Prompt!)
2. Type cd ~/.ssh. This will take you to the root directory for Git
   (Likely C:\Users[YOUR-USER-NAME].ssh\ on Windows)
3. Within the .ssh folder, there should be these two files: id_rsa and
   id_rsa.pub. These are the files that tell your computer how to
   communicate with GitHub, BitBucket, or any other Git based service.
   Type ls to see a directory listing. If those two files don't show
   up, proceed to the next step. NOTE: Your SSH keys must be named
   id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in order for Git, GitHub, and BitBucket to
   recognize them by default.
4. To create the SSH keys, type ssh-keygen -t rsa -C
   "your_email@example.com". This will create both id_rsa and
   id_rsa.pub files.
5. Now, go and open id_rsa.pub in your favorite text editor (you can do
   this via Windows Explorer or the OSX Finder if you like, typing open
   . will open the folder).
6. Copy the contents--exactly as it appears,
       with no extra spaces or lines--of id_rsa.pub and paste it into
       GitHub and/or BitBucket under the Account Settings > SSH Keys. NOTE:
       I like to give the SSH key a descriptive name, usually with the name
       of the workstation I'm on along with the date.
7. Now that you've added your public key to Github and/or BitBucket,
   try to git push again and see if it works. It should!

More help available from [GitHub on creating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

Comment: Thanks will look into this. "At the prompt, type a secure passphrase". Can this be anything i want?

Comment: @erikos93 You can add anything which you want.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :/ I tried all the steps twice with no luck.

Comment: This worked for me after lots of other things didn't

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.  Make sure and remember the passphrase, as Visual Studio 2022 will ask for it.

Answer (score 4):

This can be your ssh key is not authorised - Permission denied (publickey).

**`Solution 1`**

Check if GitHub protocols are not from `ssh` to `https`

check remote url

```
git remote -v`
```

Change remote url

```
git remote set-url origin https://URL
```

**`Solution 2`**

- Generate a SSH key on your computer
- Login to your GitHub account
- Add the newly generated SSH Key to your account through this
  [link](https://github.com/settings/ssh)
- Try again to git clone the project.

if after setting ssh key it still fails you might require system restart

**`Solution 3`**

This is not a solution just work around for newbies to clone public repo without caring protocols

Use this example

```
git clone https://github.com/%REPOSITORYFOLDER%/%REPOSITORYNAME%.git
```

Instead of

```
git clone git@github.com:%REPOSITORYFOLDER%/%REPOSITORYNAME%.git
```

> all these solutions are collected from different sources will update
>   it if more solution found which works for such scenarios

Comment: restart the machine works every single time for me.

Comment: For me it helped to change remote URL protocol from ssh to https

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by duplicate ssh key on your machine or its complete absence.

$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
This should return an ssh key, if output is empty, use below command to create ssh key(Linux/Mac):

$ `ssh-keygen`
Then fetch the key using this command
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
 This is your SSH key. Copy and add this key to your SSH keys in on git. To navigate: 
`click on photo in top right of any page -> settings -> SSH and GPG Keys -> add SSH Key`
and add the key